# New-AzureRmWebAppBackup errors out on "master" db

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm attempting to script an Azure Web App backup in PowerShell.

These commands:

```
$DatabaseBackupSetting = New-AzureRmWebAppDatabaseBackupSetting -Name $DatabaseName `
-ConnectionString $ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString -DatabaseType "SqlAzure"

New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $Site -StorageAccountUrl $SasUrl `
-Databases $DatabaseBackupSetting -BackupName ($Site + "_backup_" + (Get-Date -Format FileDateTimeUniversal)).ToLower()
```

Should back up the site and the attached db.

Here is the connection string I'm passing in to `New-AzureRmWebAppDatabaseBackupSetting`:

```
Server=tcp:[MYSERVER].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=demo-dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=demoadmin;Password=[MY_PASSWORD];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

When I run the `New-AzureRmWebAppBackup` command and check the status I see:

```
The server principal "demoadmin" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.
Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'demoadmin'.
```

I can't figure out how to tell the command to ignore the "master" db.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is 'demoadmin' the SQL Administrator of the Azure SQL Database Instance?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft No. I am using the connection string from the web app. I don't have access to the admin uname/password. I only want to backup the database that this user has access to. Is this not possible with this command?

Comment: A contained database user might have limited permissions in the database, and so they can't request a copy of the whole database be sent to a storage account of their choice.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So there's no way to just back up the database we want? Again, we don't care about backing up the master db.

Comment: The SQL Administrator can export or copy any database.  A non administrator may not be able do do this through PowerShell, though a database user with sufficient permermissions should be able to export the database with SSMS or sqlpackage.exe.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export